# how to capture an image in background without using the camera application

Tags: android, camera

I have an android app which consists of a Button.
When you click on Button, an image should be captured from the camera without opening the camera application (the image should be captured in background).
How to implement this feature?

Comment: Go through this link http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html  (Read "Using the camera API" in that tutorial)

Comment: https://github.com/kevalpatel2106/android-hidden-camera - You can use this to capture image without displaying preview.

Comment: @KevalPatel that is useless library with thousand of errors, please fix error first on that.

Comment: @KevalPatel Yes, even I'm facing issues capturing in background using service/work manager. please fix the issue or let me know how to make the required changes, i have opened the issue on your repo as well

Answer (score 24):

Here is my whole working project of How to capture image in background without SurfaceView.

// You can start your service to capturing image wherever you want not should from activity.

also need to ask need permission in your Activity

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
startActivityForResult(intent, APP_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
}
```

handle intent in click or where you needed

```
Intent front_translucent = new Intent(getApplication()
                        .getApplicationContext(), CameraService.class);
                front_translucent.putExtra("Front_Request", true);
                front_translucent.putExtra("Quality_Mode",
                        camCapture.getQuality());
                getApplication().getApplicationContext().startService(
                        front_translucent);


public class CamerService extends Service implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    // Camera variables
    // a surface holder
    // a variable to control the camera
    private Camera mCamera;
    // the camera parameters
    private Parameters parameters;
    private Bitmap bmp;
    FileOutputStream fo;
    private String FLASH_MODE;
    private int QUALITY_MODE = 0;
    private boolean isFrontCamRequest = false;
    private Camera.Size pictureSize;
    SurfaceView sv;
    private SurfaceHolder sHolder;
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
    public Intent cameraIntent;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    Editor editor;
    int width = 0, height = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    private Camera openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
        }
        int cameraCount = 0;
        Camera cam = null;
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                try {
                    cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    Log.e("Camera",
                            "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    /*
                     * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     * "Front Camera failed to open", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                     * .show();
                     */
                }
            }
        }
        return cam;
    }

    private void setBesttPictureResolution() {
        // get biggest picture size
        width = pref.getInt("Picture_Width", 0);
        height = pref.getInt("Picture_height", 0);

        if (width == 0 | height == 0) {
            pictureSize = getBiggesttPictureSize(parameters);
            if (pictureSize != null)
                parameters
                        .setPictureSize(pictureSize.width, pictureSize.height);
            // save width and height in sharedprefrences
            width = pictureSize.width;
            height = pictureSize.height;
            editor.putInt("Picture_Width", width);
            editor.putInt("Picture_height", height);
            editor.commit();

        } else {
            // if (pictureSize != null)
            parameters.setPictureSize(width, height);
        }
    }

    private Camera.Size getBiggesttPictureSize(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
        Camera.Size result = null;

        for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
            if (result == null) {
                result = size;
            } else {
                int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                int newArea = size.width * size.height;

                if (newArea > resultArea) {
                    result = size;
                }
            }
        }

        return (result);
    }

    /** Check if this device has a camera */
    private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    /** Check if this device has front camera */
    private boolean checkFrontCamera(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
            // this device has front camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no front camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    private class TakeImage extends AsyncTask<Intent, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Intent... params) {
            takeImage(params[0]);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        }
    }

    private synchronized void takeImage(Intent intent) {

        if (checkCameraHardware(getApplicationContext())) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                String flash_mode = extras.getString("FLASH");
                FLASH_MODE = flash_mode;

                boolean front_cam_req = extras.getBoolean("Front_Request");
                isFrontCamRequest = front_cam_req;

                int quality_mode = extras.getInt("Quality_Mode");
                QUALITY_MODE = quality_mode;
            }

            if (isFrontCamRequest) {

                // set flash 0ff
                FLASH_MODE = "off";
                // only for gingerbread and newer versions
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {

                    mCamera = openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread();
                    if (mCamera != null) {

                        try {
                            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(sv.getHolder());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "API dosen't support front camera",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });

                            stopSelf();
                        }
                        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();  
                        pictureSize = getBiggesttPictureSize(parameters);
                        if (pictureSize != null)
                            parameters
                                    .setPictureSize(pictureSize.width, pictureSize.height);

                        // set camera parameters
                        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                        mCamera.startPreview();
                        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);

                        // return 4;

                    } else {
                        mCamera = null;
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Your Device dosen't have Front Camera !",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });

                        stopSelf();
                    }
                    /*
                     * sHolder = sv.getHolder(); // tells Android that this
                     * surface will have its data // constantly // replaced if
                     * (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
                     * 
                     * sHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS)
                     */
                } else {
                    if (checkFrontCamera(getApplicationContext())) {
                        mCamera = openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread();

                        if (mCamera != null) {

                            try {
                                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(sv.getHolder());
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                getApplicationContext(),
                                                "API dosen't support front camera",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });

                                stopSelf();
                            }
                            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();  
                            pictureSize = getBiggesttPictureSize(parameters);
                            if (pictureSize != null)
                                parameters
                                        .setPictureSize(pictureSize.width, pictureSize.height);

                            // set camera parameters
                            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                            mCamera.startPreview();
                            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
                            // return 4;

                        } else {
                            mCamera = null;
                            /*
                             * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                             * "API dosen't support front camera",
                             * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             */
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Your Device dosen't have Front Camera !",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }
                            });

                            stopSelf();

                        }
                        // Get a surface
                        /*
                         * sHolder = sv.getHolder(); // tells Android that this
                         * surface will have its data // constantly // replaced
                         * if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
                         * 
                         * sHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS
                         * );
                         */
                    }

                }

            } else {

                if (mCamera != null) {
                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                    mCamera.release();
                    mCamera = Camera.open();
                } else
                    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

                try {
                    if (mCamera != null) {
                        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(sv.getHolder());
                        parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                        if (FLASH_MODE == null || FLASH_MODE.isEmpty()) {
                            FLASH_MODE = "auto";
                        }
                        parameters.setFlashMode(FLASH_MODE);
                        // set biggest picture
                        setBesttPictureResolution();
                        // log quality and image format
                        Log.d("Qaulity", parameters.getJpegQuality() + "");
                        Log.d("Format", parameters.getPictureFormat() + "");

                        // set camera parameters
                        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                        mCamera.startPreview();
                        Log.d("ImageTakin", "OnTake()");
                        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
                    } else {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Camera is unavailable !",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                    // return 4;

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.e("TAG", "CmaraHeadService()::takePicture", e);
                }
                // Get a surface
                /*
                 * sHolder = sv.getHolder(); // tells Android that this surface
                 * will have its data constantly // replaced if
                 * (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
                 * 
                 * sHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
                 */

            }

        } else {
            // display in long period of time
            /*
             * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
             * "Your Device dosen't have a Camera !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
             * .show();
             */
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Your Device dosen't have a Camera !",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            stopSelf();
        }

        // return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // sv = new SurfaceView(getApplicationContext());
        cameraIntent = intent;
        Log.d("ImageTakin", "StartCommand()");
        pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
        editor = pref.edit();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.width = 1;
        params.height = 1;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 0;
        sv = new SurfaceView(getApplicationContext());

        windowManager.addView(sv, params);
        sHolder = sv.getHolder();
        sHolder.addCallback(this);

        // tells Android that this surface will have its data constantly
        // replaced
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
            sHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        return 1;
    }

    Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            // decode the data obtained by the camera into a Bitmap
            Log.d("ImageTakin", "Done");
            if (bmp != null)
                bmp.recycle();
            System.gc();
            bmp = decodeBitmap(data);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if (bmp != null && QUALITY_MODE == 0)
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, bytes);
            else if (bmp != null && QUALITY_MODE != 0)
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, QUALITY_MODE, bytes);

            File imagesFolder = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MYGALLERY");
            if (!imagesFolder.exists())
                imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
            File image = new File(imagesFolder, System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + ".jpg");

            // write the bytes in file
            try {
                fo = new FileOutputStream(image);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "FileNotFoundException", e);
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
            try {
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "fo.write::PictureTaken", e);
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }

            // remember close de FileOutput
            try {
                fo.close();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                            Uri.parse("file://"
                                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
                else {
                    MediaScannerConnection
                            .scanFile(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    new String[] { image.toString() },
                                    null,
                                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                                        public void onScanCompleted(
                                                String path, Uri uri) {
                                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned "
                                                    + path + ":");
                                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri="
                                                    + uri);
                                        }
                                    });
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
            /*
             * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
             * "Your Picture has been taken !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             */
            com.integreight.onesheeld.Log.d("Camera", "Image Taken !");
            if (bmp != null) {
                bmp.recycle();
                bmp = null;
                System.gc();
            }
            mCamera = null;
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Your Picture has been taken !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });
            stopSelf();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
        if (sv != null)
            windowManager.removeView(sv);
        Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
        // You can also include some extra data.
        intent.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (cameraIntent != null)
            new TakeImage().execute(cameraIntent);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeBitmap(byte[] data) {

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bfOptions.inDither = false; // Disable Dithering mode
        bfOptions.inPurgeable = true; // Tell to gc that whether it needs free
                                        // memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
        bfOptions.inInputShareable = true; // Which kind of reference will be
                                            // used to recover the Bitmap data
                                            // after being clear, when it will
                                            // be used in the future
        bfOptions.inTempStorage = new byte[32 * 1024];

        if (data != null)
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,
                    bfOptions);

        return bitmap;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey Heema , in this service on debugging i am getting mCamera = getCameraInstance(); as null

Comment: @sid Hey, If you get null when calling getCameraInstance() so your camera is still unavailable. Try to stop your service after finishing from saving your image in mobile storage. then trigger your service again to repeat the job. Try it and if there any problem let me know.

Comment: hey Heema , i am getting an error java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed  when my device do not have memory card in it but it works fine with memory card , i only encounter this error when my device do not have sd card in it.Do you have any solution for this error ?

Comment: Hey @sid Try to change path of store from external memory to internal memory. So change line of "File imagesFolder = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MYGALLERY");" 

Change to Using the Internal Storage Check this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: Thank you so much. Working perfectly :-)

Comment: @Suji Great..Enjoy Coding :)

Comment: need to add the permission: 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

Comment: This is a working code;

You have to add some permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


and register your service:
   <service android:name=".CamerService"/>

Comment: i got error but when i change TYPE of LayoutParams to "LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST", its working fine...you can also check it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400539/windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window/37113007#37113007 ...!!! thanks @Heema.

Comment: hey this is working like a charm but the pictures taken are light green in shade. How to take normal pictures ??? @Suji any idea???

Comment: Hey, I'm so happy that can help you. related to green picture try to change quality mode to be 100 hope to work with you @Kaushal28

Comment: @Heema I've already tried changing it to 100. But not working.

Comment: what is camCapture here..   front_translucent.putExtra("Quality_Mode",
                        camCapture.getQuality());

Comment: @Avinash camCapture it's just an object I used it to save some camera attributes. You can set any number for camera quality.

Comment: Perfect Solution..!

Comment: Thank you for this solution, but in my case the picture is flipped 90° clockwise, `Camera.setDisplayOrientation()` not working

Comment: @hiddeneyes02 It seems like need a custom fixing depend on device type. This answer maybe help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017148/android-camera-setdisplayorientation90-fails-in-different-devices

Comment: Sorry but how is this supposed to be used? It's not only call the service, right? (because it doesn't do anything by just doing that - using Lollipop 5.1 to test this, because I don't have older devices, but for newer ones I'll use camera2) Am I supposed to start the camera or something? (probably not because the service already does that?) Or if it has to do with creating a SurfaceHolder, is there any example I could look at?

Comment: Actually, never mind. I forgot to add the service to the manifest. It's working perfectly. Just needs some improvements to increase the brightness, but except that it's perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @DADi590 Happy to hearing that's working perfectly...Enjoy coding :)

Comment: Hi (again ahah). I was thinking in incorporating this into a project I started on GitHub. I'm also learning about licenses. And it seems StackOverflow has the CC BY-SA license on every answer (unless people add a license of their own, I believe). Would you mind if I added it to my project (with credits, of course)? I'm asking because various times people may not realize the answers have a default open-source-only license (I didn't). In my case, I licensed my project with Apache 2 which incompatible with CC BY-SA, for example. If you'd prefer I didn't no problem at all.

Comment: Hi @DADi590
Happy to hear from you again. Sure, I don't mind and appreciate your credits. waiting your project URL to know more about it.

Comment: @IbrahimAbdelGawad Hi. Cool, thanks! Here is the project URL: https://github.com/DADi590/V.I.S.O.R.---A-real-assistant--Android-Client - it's a virtual assistant. Sorry for the delay xD. This class is not there yet. Still needs testing, after I made some changes on it to improve its code (got help from IntelliJ's Inspections, which I am in love with hahaha) and remove parts that I didn't need (anything below API 15, which is not supported by the app).

Answer (score -1):

You can do that using CameraX. It is used to create your own camera app so you can do that by just omitting the preview part. Go to the below link for a small tutorial on cameraX https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#0 and you can just copy paste the code. For `androidx.camera.view.PreviewView` just put `width=0` and `height=0` and you will get the required result.