# Android service to capture a image from the front cam(in the background)

Tags: android

I want to run a service in an android app that captures a image from the front camera (in the background) without users notice and saves the image so that i can mail it later. Any help is really appreciated.Thanks in Advance:-)

Comment: This link is for record video in background. So according to it you can implement picture capture code http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/845710/Android-Record-video-in-background-and-simultaneou

Comment: Here is same question asked as yours! Refer it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752637/how-to-capture-an-image-in-background-without-using-the-camera-application