# Take a picture in background on Android

Tags: java, android, camera

So I want to use the camera intent

```
Intent intent =new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
```

and I want to do something while the picture is capturing, and my question is can I do the capturing in background while on the display is something else and than show the picture ?. Thanks in advance for help

Comment: I think this question should be what you serch on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752637/how-to-capture-an-image-in-background-without-using-the-camera-application

Comment: not really i want to use the camera app because its way better than writing your own code for the camera, thats why I use the Intent. But thanks it can be useful.

Comment: In this case you should onActivityResult(), but you can't do it in background, there is not other solution

Comment: I want to see the preview of the camera and then take a picture, when I press capture it should do it in background and display something else while capturing.

Comment: As Youcam39 already pointed out correctly - if you want this type of control you've to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a snippet from a project a did before, I hope it will help you:

```
  // Open the camera and take a picture
public void openCamera() {
    Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    getIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(getIntent, SEND_MESSAGE_IMG_REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK);
}

// handle the result from camera
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == SEND_MESSAGE_IMG_REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        // do a background task to handle the captured image (upload it to a server or something like that)



    }
}
```

Comment: I want to display something between the camera preview and taking a picture so when I press the capture button i want to display an image and then take the picture while displaying the image.