# Can we use takePicture() in android without camera preview? I need to take a picture secretly for security purposes

Tags: android, image, camera, android-camera, capture

I tried few codes from here :

[How to capture an image in background without using the camera application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752637/how-to-capture-an-image-in-background-without-using-the-camera-application)

and this

[Android Camera API Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html).

This question may seem duplicated, but I really want to know that can this be done over API level 21?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google says it is depricated

[check here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)

but they are using it 

[here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)

I am really confused. Really need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to android.developer.com, no.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

"Important: Call startPreview() to start updating the preview surface. Preview must be started before you can take a picture."

Comment: I've read that earlier and was trying to hack something out of it. But as it seems it is not allowing me what ever I try. Thanks by the way.