# Camera not taking image when app is in kill/background state

Tags: android, service, permissions, background, camera

I'm trying to build a security app (on lock screen when user enter wrong password, then the app would capture the photo of that person)!

The app is capturing image perfect on wrong password, but the issue is when the app is in a kill or background state, then the camera is not capturing any image. The service is also running in background. Please let me know if any solution exist. Thanks in advance!

Sometimes the following dialog appear when I immediately open the app by entering correct password:
[image: Permission Dialogbox]

I think that's because of dangerous permission, but there are many apps available on PlayStore with these features.

Any suggestions will be helpful :)

Comment: Can you please share the code where you are accessing the camera in service, and also share the permissions which you are asking on run time.
Also share your android version.

Comment: I used the following link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752637/how-to-capture-an-image-in-background-without-using-the-camera-application

Comment: found any solution so far ?